# gradient ascent for activation map vizualization

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, gradient, loss-function

I'm trying to code a gradient ascent that makes a random blur image change to maximize some given activation map in my conv based net (Yolov7). I followed a github (https://github.com/dd2-42/Unloading-the-Cognitive-Overload-in-Machine-Learning/blob/main/Computer_Vision/XAI/CNN_Visualizations/CNN_Visualizations_01.ipynb) and now wondering 2 things : if the loss function is correct and if code can be reorganized to not encounter error  `RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation` (see https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/39141)
based on this

```
def gradient_ascent(self):
    input_noise = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224, requires_grad=True, device=self.device)
    self.model.eval()
        
    # activate the hook
    layer = self.model.model[self.layer_idx]
    handle = layer.register_forward_hook(self.hook_fn)
        
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([input_noise], lr=self.lr)
        
    for i in range(self.steps):
        self.model(input_noise)
        loss = -self.activations[0][:, self.feature_map_idx, :, :].mean()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optimizer.step()
        
    handle.remove()
    return input_noise
```

I wonder if removing the `requires_grad=True` is a way to deal with the error? What do you think of the loss function?

any help welcome
Thanks

Comment: you ought to reframe this to be gradient *descent*. that is the usual term.

Comment: no, it's not backprop to calculate the weights of the CNN, it's gradually modifying an img to maximize the activation map from a CNN that's already learned its weights "Wi"

Comment: so, it's Grad-CAM?

Comment: no it's actally called gradient ascent, it doesn't rely on a specific img, it takes a random noise img as input bc what is visualized is what would maximize some activation map